# measure amount of data read from /dev/random

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, gpg, random

**background**

I have written a collection of bash scripts (most of them in German only yet [but if you are interested](http://www.openpgp-schulungen.de/download/); download the archive not the single scripts) which help users create high-quality OpenPGP keys. These scripts are typically used in a "secure" environment (Linux live CD/DVD). This leads to the problem that these systems have hardly any entropy.

For obvious reasons `gpg` reads a lot of data from `/dev/random` which means that my poor users (at worst those with a SSD) have to type a lot on the keyboard in order to create the required entropy.

I have written a simple script which shows the users the current size of the entropy pool (which changes quickly between 0 and 64 while `gpg` reads data). I would like to also show a kind of progress bar so that the users can see that they have generated e.g. about 50% of the needed entropy. The required amount should always be (nearly) the same (until I change the key size).

**question**

So the question is: How can I (easily) measure the amount of data which has been read from `/dev/random` (by a certain process or the whole system)? The only idea I had up to now is attaching `strace` to `gpg` and trace the `read()`s from the respective file descriptor. But maybe there is a much better solution.

Comment: Did you see this in `/proc` for getting the size of the entropy pool? `/proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail`.

Comment: Also just curious, I've only typically seen `/dev/urandom` used (in security applications too), which would make your concern moot (I think). Gilles answer here kind of backs me up on this, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32988/why-does-dd-from-dev-random-give-different-file-sizes. Just wondering if you were aware of this. So is `/dev/random` even needed here?

Comment: This looked related too: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94206/how-to-determine-which-processes-are-using-how-much-entropy-from-dev-urandom

Comment: @slm [comment 1] "I have written a simple script which shows the users the current size of the entropy pool" What you you think where I get this data from? [comment 2] GnuPG makes heavy use of `/dev/random`. You don't even need `strace` to find that out: GnuPG often blocks (on systems with little entropy at least) and it would not block it it used `/dev/urandom`. They use `urandom`, too, but for less important data only. These people have a very clear attitude towards entropy quality... Gilles' answers don't help me.

Comment: Fair enough, just directing these as potential leads for you. Will keep looking 8-)

Comment: @HaukeLaging `/dev/random` does not give you “better quality” entropy than `/dev/urandom`. Either the machine is freshly installed and they might not have enough entropy (and then `/dev/random` tends to block), or the machine has sufficient entropy and then **`/dev/urandom` is as good as `/dev/random`**. What Linux calls the “size of the entropy pool” is not relevant to the security of keys generated from `/dev/urandom`.

Comment: @Gilles That is a strong statement (and discussing that would be OT here...) and I am absolutely sure that the GnuPG development community would not accept that (of course, that alone makes it neither true nor wrong). They even use an algorithm which needs about three bytes of random input for every random byte they actually use.

Answer (score 4):

If a little redirection is acceptable, then [`pv`](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml) is a good way in general to achieve this type of thing, *but* GPG has (unsurprisingly) `/dev/random` hard-coded into it, so that's not going to work here without some hackery. On linux, using [`unshare`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81003/making-a-process-read-a-different-file-for-the-same-filename) to temporarily overlay `/dev/random` is probably the least disagreeable, though it requires root permissions :

```
mkfifo $HOME/rngfifo
pv -s 300 /dev/random > $HOME/rngfifo
```

`pv` will block until there's a reader on the fifo. Then as root or via `sudo`:

```
unshare -m -- sh -c "mount --bind $HOME/rngfifo /dev/random && gpg --gen-key [...]"
```

One obvious possible useful source of data is the random device driver itself (`drivers/char/random.c`). It supports a "debug" parameter, but sadly in the versions I've checked it's if-defined out (`#if 0`, 2.6.x and 3.4.x), and has been removed completely in recent kernels in favour of [ftrace](http://elinux.org/Ftrace) support. The driver makes an ftrace call (`trace_extract_entropy()`) each time data is read. For this, it seems overkill to me, as does [systemtap](https://serverfault.com/questions/327985/linux-io-monitoring-per-file), and the other [tracing and debugging options (PDF)](http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/lcjp13_zannoni.pdf).

A simple (but unappealing to most) option is to use an injected library to wrap the relevant `open()` and `read()` calls at the libc interface, similar to the solution to this question: [Dynamic file content generation: Satisfying a 'file open' by a 'process execution'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76462/dynamic-file-content-generation-satisfying-a-file-open-by-a-process-executio) . If you wrap `open64()` are arrange for it to cache the descriptor when `/dev/random` is opened you can log the size of each `read()`.

To help get the entropy rolling in, I highly recommend [asciipacman](http://marquisdegeek.com/rnd_pacman.php) ;-)