# Pipe Viewer - Progress monitor performance consequence

Tags: text-processing, performance, cpu, pv

I am writing a batch script to sort through gigs and gigs of data. All of the data is text but the script will take a long long time to execute. I would like to give some visual indication that the script is running.  I found the program called `pv` which allows you to create progress bars and other nice `CLI` progress indicators.

My question is what type of impact does something like this have on performance and are there any other alternatives without me having to reinvent the wheel.

I have googled it to death and haven't found anything which is surprising as I would assume you would only show progress on long tasks where performance is important.  But I suppose I am using clock cycles and you could also use it to measure disk I/O or network data transfers where using a few cycles for a progress indication wouldn't matter.

Any ideas?

P.S. I have also considered using the `echo -ne` trick to create my own but in order to make it feasible I would have to use the `%` operator on every loop and only take action ever 100th or so loop but that is A LOT of wasted calculations...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There will typically (lacking [zero-copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-copy) trickery) be measurable overhead due to the extra IPC: copying the data from one process to another, rather than the "workhorse" process reading files directly. A pipe may also result in loss of performance (or functionality) for [other reasons](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Memory_002dmapped-I_002fO.html): with piped input a process cannot `seek()` on its input, and cannot `mmap()` it.

Generally though, the main performance bottlenecks are probably disk I/O, and CPU compute time (which presumably is intensive in your case). These may be very much larger than the IPC overhead, but there are *many* variables here (CPU type, disk type *and* fileystem type, available physical RAM, OS and version, libc and version — at least).

You can get a rough idea of performance with some quick tests, taking care to flush the disk cache before each one (I'm using linux, I use [this method](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87909/31352)) in between each test.

```
# time ( pv -pt somethinglarge.iso | sha256sum )
[...]
real    0m8.066s
user    0m5.146s 
sys     0m1.075s

# time ( sha256sum somethinglarge.iso )
[...]
real    0m7.913s
user    0m5.064s
sys     0m0.309s
```

Note the similar real and user and  times, and the marked increase in *system* time for the piped case due to the extra copying.

On some OSes, specifically Linux, you may be able to read [per-process I/O stats from `/proc` (see 3.3)](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt) (you'll need `CONFIG_TASKSTATS` enabled in the kernel for this). This isn't as easy or as slick as `pv`, but it's low-overhead. `pidstat` uses this, it can be used to show real-time throughput (rate) on a PID, but it's less useful as a completion indicator.

A similar linux option (this one doesn't need `CONFIG_TASKSTATS`), given a process and file descriptor, you can track the file descriptor's offset in `/proc/PID/fdinfo/FD` (the `pos:` field). Here's a toy script that shows this:

```
FILE=/tmp/some-large-input
SZ=$(stat -c "%s" "$FILE")

# start slow process in background
( some-slow-command $FILE ) &
PID=$!
FD=/proc/$PID/fdinfo/3       # some experimentation required
# or iterate over /proc/$PID/fd/* with readlink 

# start %-ometer in background, exits when FD disappears
(
while nawk '/^pos:/{printf("%i\n",$2*100/'$SZ')}' $FD 2>/dev/null ; do
    sleep 5  # adjust
done | dialog --gauge "$PID: processing $FILE ($SZ bytes)" 10 60
) &

wait $PID
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo 100 | dialog --gauge "$PID: completed $FILE ($SZ bytes)" 10 60
else 
    echo ...
fi
```

(Caveat: not accurate for small files, libc stdio buffering will skew the results.)

Other options that occur to me right now:

- use `lsof` to [monitor a processes fd offsets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/238140/1955371)
  not exactly lightweight, but multi-platform, and you can start it on any long-running process after the fact, which you cannot do with `pv` (it's not pretty either, since `lsof` refuses to give both the size and offset in one go)
- something hackish with `LD_PRELOAD` and some stubs which track data read/write, this too is multi-platform, but I think you'd have to write your own (I don't know any that does exactly this, but here's a [related answer of mine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117594/measure-amount-of-data-read-from-dev-random))
- *Update:* someone has gone to the trouble of writing a general purpose  transfer monitor tool [cv](https://github.com/Xfennec/cv) for use with *coreutils* commands on Linux. It uses similar logic to the `/proc` `fdinfo` approach (as demonstrated in the shell hack above). It also has a background mode where it scans /proc and reports on transfers in progress as it finds them. See related question [Is it possible to see cp speed and percent copied?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65077/is-it-possible-to-see-cp-speed-and-copied)

Comment: +1 This has given me some great leads, I am gonna put this together and I will likely be accepting your answer shortly. I am going to try to track the `file descriptor's offset` as my files are rather sizable I do not think stdio buffering will be an issue.  Let you know soon!  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `pv` command does not have much overhead on CPU in cases where I use it (mostly using zfs send and receive actions). If you just want to know that it is still processing you can just use `pv` to count data that is piped through it. If you want an estimate time of completion you might want to add a pre-command which counts the sum of data to be processed with `pv -s <SIZE>`. Such pre-calculations might cause some overhead.