# Get percentage information from 7z command in bash

Tags: bash, 7z

With archives containing more than 30 files, list of extracted files quickly stops being interesting. I a making a script that extracts a `.war` archive into a tomcat app folder:

[image: image description]

When looking in help for `7z` command, I noticed this line:

```
  -bd: Disable percentage indicator
```

Well, I would really like to **enable** percentage indicator and use it instead of insane file list. How would I do it? Something like:

[image: image description]

But frankly, one line percentage indicator like bellow would be enough:

```
Progress: 30%
```

Comment: unfortunately it seems to not be possible in a clean way http://superuser.com/questions/702122/how-to-show-extraction-progress-of-7zip-inside-cmd

Comment: @lese So the switch in help is just an error then?

Comment: If you don't require 7-zip to be used you could try `pv <file> | jar xf /dev/stdin`.

Comment: @Marco Seems that `jar` is not installed on debian by default... 7zip was. Isn't there another alternative?

Comment: Neither `pv`, nor `jar` is installed in a default Debian installation. If you only can use certain tools you should mention that in the question. This task is not easy using arbitrary tools, but if you require only a limited toolset, I doubt there will be many answers.

Comment: @Marco Well, I already actually gave up. Further this question is about `7z` specifically, so maybe someone could post one of these hacky approaches mentioned on superuser.

Comment: You could run `7z` or `unzip` and then use [pmonitor:](https://github.com/dspinellis/pmonitor) `pmonitor --command=7z --interval=1` and continuously monitor the file progress.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to do this using standard utilities, you are definitely going to have to find a very hacky workaround.  Otherwise use `whiptail` --
 http://xmodulo.com/create-dialog-boxes-interactive-shell-script.html or `pv` --
 http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml.

Answer (score 0):

You're *really* using `p7zip` v9.20, the portable version for Unix. *7zip* is a Windows program that has a GUI and command-line operation, its documentation doesn't necessarily always apply to `p7zip`. v9.20  quite old now (~2011), though there were no new releases until 2015. The distributed man pages are untouched since 2007, even in the latest version.

The portable `p7zip` v16.02 *does* have a progress indicator (and -bd does disable it). There doesn't seem to be a Changelog just for the portable version so I can't say when it was added, other than after v9.20.1 which I have confirmed does not have it either.

Otherwise, general purpose solutions include `pmonitor` (requires `lsof`) as suggested by Marco, or [`progress`](https://github.com/Xfennec/progress) (Linux specific). See also this question for further information: [Pipe Viewer - Progress monitor performance consequence](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191386/pipe-viewer-progress-monitor-performance-consequence/191493) (my answer there has a script that shows how you might extract the required information from `/proc` without extra tools).